# What is the difference between 'toBe' and 'toEqual' in Jest?

Tags: testing, jestjs

Jest documentation reads:

> toBe just checks that a value is what you expect. It uses === to check strict equality.

And for `toEqual`:

> Use .toEqual when you want to check that two objects have the same value. This matcher recursively checks the equality of all fields, rather than checking for object identity—this is also known as "deep equal". For example, toEqual and toBe behave differently in this test suite, so all the tests pass.

```js
const x = { a: { b: 3 } };
const y = { a: { b: 3 } };

expect(x).toEqual(y);
expect(x).toBe(y);
```

In this case, `toEqual` passes but `toBe` fails. I understand that `toEqual` passes because it does a *deep equal* check. Why is `toBe` failing in this case?

Also, are there best practices for using `toBe` and `toEqual` (not just in Jest but in other testing frameworks, too)?

Comment: FYI: The documentation about the two methods are very common nowadays:
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#toequalvalue
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobevalue
And both methods use `Object.is` internally.

Comment: Here's an explanation in codespeak: `const a = { foo: 'bar' }; const b = a; b.foo = 'baz'; expect(a.foo).toBe('baz')`. When you change `b` you change `a`, and when you change `a` you change `b`, because they reference the same object. That's what `toBe()` checks, when used with objects.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

It fails cause `x` and `y` are different instances and not equal as in `(x === y) === false`. You can use `toBe` for primitives like strings,  numbers or booleans for everything else use `toEqual`. For example

```js
x = 4 
y = 4
x === y // true

x = 'someString'
y = 'someString'
x === y // true
```

Even empty objects are not equal

```js
x = {}
y = {}
x === y //false
```

Comment: So I guess for non-primitives, `toBe` checks the memory address of the variable?

Comment: Its just a simple JS feature that you can compare primitives using `===`

Comment: Is there any reason to use `toBe`?

Comment: `toBe` or not `toBe`, that is the question.

Comment: @ThomasChampion Don't Jest... `toBe()` || `not.toBe()`, that is the test.

Comment: theQuestion = toBe || !toBe;

Comment: Really useful explanation!

Comment: @OliverShaw `toBe` or `toEqual` can be used with primitives, but `toBe` is specifically useful for reference equality aka. when you want to assert that it is literally the same instance of an object.

Comment: So basically `toBe` compares referential equality and `toEqual` compares deep properties? This answer is pretty poorly written. On one hand you say that we should use `toEqual` for objects as in `expect({}).toEqual({}) === true`, but in next sentence you say that _"empty objects are not equal"_.

Answer (score 28):

Suppose there are two players with same name and both of them scored 20.

```
let player1 = {
    name: "Amit",
    score: 20,
}

let player2 = {
    name: "Amit",
    score: 20,
}
```

**Now I have a function which gives me 1st player.**

```
function getFirstPlayer(player1,player2){
    return player1;
}
```

How will I test this function?

```
# 1st way
expect(getFirstPlayer(player1,player2)).toBe(player1); // Passes
expect(getFirstPlayer(player1,player2)).not.toBe(player2); // Passes

# 2nd way
expect(getFirstPlayer(player1,player2)).toEqual(player1); // Pases
expect(getFirstPlayer(player1,player2)).not.toEqual(player2); // Fails
```

`toBe` tests Identity and `toEqual` tests features. So twin kids can have same features but their real identity is different from each other.
The way this function is designed we should use `toBe`.

**Now I have a another function which increases the player score.**

```
function addScore(player,scoreToAdd){
    player.score += scoreToAdd;
}
```

How will I test this function?

```
# 1st way
addScore(player1,20);
expect(player1).toBe({name:"Amit", score:40});  // Fails

# 2nd way
addScore(player1,20);
expect(player1).toEqual({name:"Amit", score:40});  // Passes
```

Did you notice that in 1st way we are passing a new player like entity in right hand side. Is there any chance that `player1` has the same identity of newly created entity? Nope. So `toBe` will always fail in this case.

2nd way passes as in `toEqual` we are comparing features. Here `player1` and newly created entity has same features.

**Note:** In context of javascript, primitive values like `"Amit"` is identity in itself. So

```
expect("Amit").toBe("Amit") // Passes
```

I have written this answer for particular case, when you get this idea of identity and features, you can implement it in your scenario.

Answer (score 21):

It is all about object references.

`.toBe` compares primitive values or checks referential identity of object instances while `toEqual` looks for deep equailty.

```js
expect({ name: 'john doe' }).toEqual({ name: 'john doe'}); // PASSES
expect({ name: 'john doe' }).toBe({ name: 'john doe'});    // FAILS
```

The second assertion fails because they are different instances even though they are deeply equal. Remember, object literal syntax creates a new instance of the base object.

```js
let a = { name: 'john doe' };
let b = a;
```

Here, the assignment operator copies the object reference stored in the variable `a` to `b`.

```js
expect(a).toBe(b); // PASSES
```

The assertion passes because 'a' and 'b' points to same object. Please note that `{ name: 'john doe' }` is not an object, it is an instruction to create one. Objects live in memory and interacted with via their references stored in a variable.

Answer (score 14):

You have also `toStrictEqual()` since [Jest v23](https://jestjs.io/blog/2018/05/29/jest-23-blazing-fast-delightful-testing#new-matchers)

Explanations: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tostrictequalvalue

There is an [ESLint plugin for Jest](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest) with a rule to enforce `toStrictEqual()`: https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-strict-equal.md

`npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-jest`

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:jest/recommended'
  ],

  rules: {
    'jest/prefer-strict-equal': 'error'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a few people saying that `.toBe()` is the same as `x === y`, but it's actually slightly different. Jest uses `Object.is(x, y)` when doing `expect(x).toBe(y)`.

- [MDN - Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)
- [Jest .toBe source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/2a92e7f49fa35b219e5099d56b0179bccc1bf53e/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts#L80)

Unless you are verifying if a value is the same as a reference (like when checking if something got deepcloned properly), you should always use `.toEqual()`. And even in the deepclone example, I think it is cleaner to just do `expect(x === y).toEqual(true)` just to remove any confusion as to what you are trying to do.

You should not expect others to know the differences between `toBe` and `toEqual`, or to even know that `Object.is` exists and how it differs from `===`. To avoid communication problems and testing issues, always use `.toEqual`, never use `.toBe`.

---

I've written up a more detailed version of this as a blog post:

- https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/why-you-should-never-use-tobe-in-jest-48ca